# How to get value in JS object?

Tags: javascript, json

I just give an example of a script that suddenly stopped working. The problem is that i cant get any values from this object, although in the past there were no problems.

```
var points = '{"points":{"point":[{"lat":"55.68504841066897","lon":"21.128827091306448"},{"lat":"55.68509585224092","lon":"21.128621818497777"},{"lat":"55.68510725162923","lon":"21.128564486280084"},{"lat":"55.685256784781814","lon":"21.128428364172578"},{"lat":"55.68540941923857","lon":"21.12827841192484"},{"lat":"55.68553472869098","lon":"21.12819341942668"},{"lat":"55.68563086912036","lon":"21.128090489655733"},{"lat":"55.685754250735044","lon":"21.128079341724515"},{"lat":"55.685868579894304","lon":"21.12806241028011"},{"lat":"55.686048371717334","lon":"21.127971885725856"},{"lat":"55.68620461039245","lon":"21.12780307419598"},{"lat":"55.686277113854885","lon":"21.127677345648408"},{"lat":"55.68637593649328","lon":"21.12757139839232"},{"lat":"55.68648599088192","lon":"21.127493027597666"},{"lat":"55.68663602694869","lon":"21.127418177202344"},{"lat":"55.68679201416671","lon":"21.12734558992088"},{"lat":"55.686920089647174","lon":"21.12726939842105"},{"lat":"55.68693928420544","lon":"21.127255652099848"},{"lat":"55.68705772049725","lon":"21.127218855544925"},{"lat":"55.68714472465217","lon":"21.127141742035747"},{"lat":"55.6871934235096","lon":"21.12712439149618"},{"lat":"55.68733625113964","lon":"21.127151465043426"},{"lat":"55.68751168437302","lon":"21.12717761658132"},{"lat":"55.687646800652146","lon":"21.127120200544596"},{"lat":"55.68781033158302","lon":"21.127034788951278"},{"lat":"55.687981490045786","lon":"21.12691568210721"},{"lat":"55.68808760493994","lon":"21.126865474507213"},{"lat":"55.68817662075162","lon":"21.126789785921574"},{"lat":"55.68830654025078","lon":"21.12668802961707"},{"lat":"55.688458336517215","lon":"21.126597672700882"},{"lat":"55.68859001621604","lon":"21.126522067934275"},{"lat":"55.68873468786478","lon":"21.126421485096216"},{"lat":"55.689044734463096","lon":"21.126208417117596"},{"lat":"55.68912017159164","lon":"21.126169441267848"},{"lat":"55.68925394676626","lon":"21.1261201556772"},{"lat":"55.68945947103202","lon":"21.12605821341276"},{"lat":"55.68962057121098","lon":"21.125976908951998"},{"lat":"55.68978569470346","lon":"21.125826286152005"},{"lat":"55.68990069441497","lon":"21.125754453241825"},{"lat":"55.68995366804302","lon":"21.125659067183733"},{"lat":"55.69000102579594","lon":"21.1256090272218"},{"lat":"55.69016573019326","lon":"21.1255088634789"},{"lat":"55.690477369353175","lon":"21.12531390041113"},{"lat":"55.69060888141394","lon":"21.125247851014137"},{"lat":"55.69067928940058","lon":"21.12515070475638"},{"lat":"55.6907766032964","lon":"21.124989185482264"},{"lat":"55.69090216420591","lon":"21.1248526442796"},{"lat":"55.69097299128771","lon":"21.124745020642877"},{"lat":"55.691056391224265","lon":"21.124557433649898"},{"lat":"55.69115781225264","lon":"21.124385772272944"},{"lat":"55.6912134680897","lon":"21.124245207756758"},{"lat":"55.691240122541785","lon":"21.124201118946075"},{"lat":"55.69127884693444","lon":"21.124075977131724"},{"lat":"55.69134992547333","lon":"21.12395158968866"},{"lat":"55.69142796099186","lon":"21.123761823400855"},{"lat":"55.691470289602876","lon":"21.123608015477657"},{"lat":"55.691630467772484","lon":"21.123296124860644"},{"lat":"55.69177580997348","lon":"21.123084481805563"},{"lat":"55.691883098334074","lon":"21.12299303524196"},{"lat":"55.691998517140746","lon":"21.122908294200897"},{"lat":"55.692141177132726","lon":"21.122815422713757"},{"lat":"55.6923047080636","lon":"21.12273939885199"},{"lat":"55.692533031105995","lon":"21.122592883184552"},{"lat":"55.69262858480215","lon":"21.122528091073036"},{"lat":"55.692712320014834","lon":"21.1224711779505"},{"lat":"55.69280887953937","lon":"21.122405463829637"},{"lat":"55.69282790645957","lon":"21.12241141498089"},{"lat":"55.69290057756007","lon":"21.122407307848334"},{"lat":"55.69293066859245","lon":"21.12237486988306"},{"lat":"55.69301373325288","lon":"21.122297504916787"},{"lat":"55.69308330304921","lon":"21.122258696705103"},{"lat":"55.69318933412433","lon":"21.121885618194938"},{"lat":"55.693208780139685","lon":"21.121837757527828"},{"lat":"55.69326653145254","lon":"21.121622258797288"},{"lat":"55.693393936380744","lon":"21.121310954913497"},{"lat":"55.693441880866885","lon":"21.121110962703824"},{"lat":"55.69349527359009","lon":"21.120854392647743"},{"lat":"55.69358579814434","lon":"21.120616095140576"},{"lat":"55.69369417615235","lon":"21.12032457254827"},{"lat":"55.69377011619508","lon":"21.120052495971322"},{"lat":"55.693774642422795","lon":"21.120002456009388"},{"lat":"55.693801464512944","lon":"21.11992777325213"},{"lat":"55.693983267992735","lon":"21.119664330035448"},{"lat":"55.69409340620041","lon":"21.119460901245475"},{"lat":"55.69415652193129","lon":"21.11929250881076"},{"lat":"55.69417831487954","lon":"21.119207181036472"},{"lat":"55.69424897432327","lon":"21.118967961519957"},{"lat":"55.694260792806745","lon":"21.118934266269207"},{"lat":"55.69426699541509","lon":"21.118877101689577"},{"lat":"55.69431468844414","lon":"21.11856361851096"},{"lat":"55.69434058852494","lon":"21.118531934916973"},{"lat":"55.69443111307919","lon":"21.118354992941022"},{"lat":"55.69457972422242","lon":"21.1182370595634"},{"lat":"55.69472850300372","lon":"21.118099931627512"},{"lat":"55.694737220183015","lon":"21.118061039596796"},{"lat":"55.69480947218835","lon":"21.117927934974432"},{"lat":"55.69499395787716","lon":"21.117815114557743"},{"lat":"55.69512295536697","lon":"21.11766935326159"},{"lat":"55.69523921236396","lon":"21.11754127778113"},{"lat":"55.695358319208026","lon":"21.117476485669613"},{"lat":"55.695498967543244","lon":"21.117387553676963"},{"lat":"55.69560918956995","lon":"21.11733608879149"},{"lat":"55.69572452455759","lon":"21.117292754352093"},{"lat":"55.695821000263095","lon":"21.11724623478949"},{"lat":"55.695909429341555","lon":"21.117141377180815"},{"lat":"55.696009173989296","lon":"21.117025455459952"},{"lat":"55.69604102522135","lon":"21.117006093263626"},{"lat":"55.696090226992965","lon":"21.116960495710373"},{"lat":"55.69625677540898","lon":"21.116869132965803"},{"lat":"55.69637831300497","lon":"21.116807106882334"},{"lat":"55.69654083810747","lon":"21.11673066392541"},{"lat":"55.696675116196275","lon":"21.116644330322742"},{"lat":"55.69678684696555","lon":"21.116551458835602"},{"lat":"55.69688340649009","lon":"21.116469986736774"},{"lat":"55.697014667093754","lon":"21.116367476060987"},{"lat":"55.69704534485936","lon":"21.11634660512209"},{"lat":"55.69713561795652","lon":"21.116271084174514"},{"lat":"55.69718171842396","lon":"21.116163125261664"},{"lat":"55.69733996875584","lon":"21.116052316501737"},{"lat":"55.697473073378205","lon":"21.11595081165433"},{"lat":"55.697658313438296","lon":"21.115931114181876"},{"lat":"55.69781731814146","lon":"21.115811336785555"},{"lat":"55.69795947521925","lon":"21.115705221891403"},{"lat":"55.698050586506724","lon":"21.115594832226634"},{"lat":"55.69814337417483","lon":"21.115462817251682"},{"lat":"55.69816265255213","lon":"21.115436078980565"},{"lat":"55.69827714934945","lon":"21.11534840427339"},{"lat":"55.69821269251406","lon":"21.115194596350193"},{"lat":"55.69802870973945","lon":"21.11485881730914"},{"lat":"55.69793617352843","lon":"21.114696208387613"},{"lat":"55.69779242388904","lon":"21.114436956122518"},{"lat":"55.697687985375524","lon":"21.114247357472777"},{"lat":"55.69759452715516","lon":"21.11412481404841"},{"lat":"55.697459829971194","lon":"21.113973017781973"},{"lat":"55.69730476476252","lon":"21.11382189206779"},{"lat":"55.69720124825835","lon":"21.113727260380983"},{"lat":"55.697076106444","lon":"21.113614523783326"},{"lat":"55.6967859249562","lon":"21.11329223960638"},{"lat":"55.69665038958192","lon":"21.113007087260485"},{"lat":"55.69655232131481","lon":"21.112801395356655"},{"lat":"55.69646816700697","lon":"21.112644569948316"},{"lat":"55.696425419300795","lon":"21.11255052499473"},{"lat":"55.69636255502701","lon":"21.112362518906593"},{"lat":"55.69635140709579","lon":"21.112339636310935"},{"lat":"55.69623523391783","lon":"21.112123718485236"},{"lat":"55.696120569482446","lon":"21.111881816759706"},{"lat":"55.696040857583284","lon":"21.11167528666556"},{"lat":"55.69595008157194","lon":"21.11142022535205"},{"lat":"55.695875734090805","lon":"21.11120472662151"},{"lat":"55.69572854787111","lon":"21.110760234296322"},{"lat":"55.69564430974424","lon":"21.11053735949099"},{"lat":"55.69553685374558","lon":"21.11026863567531"},{"lat":"55.69546644575894","lon":"21.110082305967808"},{"lat":"55.695343650877476","lon":"21.109795225784183"},{"lat":"55.69524306803942","lon":"21.1095180362463"},{"lat":"55.69515866227448","lon":"21.109181251376867"},{"lat":"55.695100324228406","lon":"21.108942283317447"},{"lat":"55.69498088210821","lon":"21.1084093619138"},{"lat":"55.69490510970354","lon":"21.108084814623"},{"lat":"55.69484299980104","lon":"21.107756663113832"},{"lat":"55.69478918798268","lon":"21.10747955739498"},{"lat":"55.694745602086186","lon":"21.10724243335426"},{"lat":"55.6946914549917","lon":"21.106920819729567"},{"lat":"55.69466907531023","lon":"21.10674454830587"},{"lat":"55.69461132399738","lon":"21.106461994349957"},{"lat":"55.6945738568902","lon":"21.106215063482523"},{"lat":"55.69453219883144","lon":"21.10587878152728"},{"lat":"55.69449230097234","lon":"21.1055772844702"},{"lat":"55.694455252960324","lon":"21.105288863182068"},{"lat":"55.69440764375031","lon":"21.104955095797777"},{"lat":"55.69435643032193","lon":"21.10461462289095"},{"lat":"55.694305300712585","lon":"21.10427993349731"},{"lat":"55.69425861351192","lon":"21.103936610743403"},{"lat":"55.69421645253897","lon":"21.10363251529634"},{"lat":"55.69416725076735","lon":"21.10329195857048"},{"lat":"55.6941232457757","lon":"21.102952240034938"},{"lat":"55.69407915696502","lon":"21.10261511988938"},{"lat":"55.694058453664184","lon":"21.102374475449324"},{"lat":"55.69406448863447","lon":"21.102328961715102"},{"lat":"55.69408108480275","lon":"21.102257715538144"},{"lat":"55.694214943796396","lon":"21.10212218016386"},{"lat":"55.69423698820174","lon":"21.10211681574583"},{"lat":"55.69442750886083","lon":"21.102087311446667"},{"lat":"55.6946084741503","lon":"21.102057807147503"},{"lat":"55.69477544166148","lon":"21.10203324817121"},{"lat":"55.69497543387115","lon":"21.102013969793916"},{"lat":"55.695172073319554","lon":"21.101996451616287"},{"lat":"55.695517072454095","lon":"21.1019354313612"},{"lat":"55.69569854065776","lon":"21.101907016709447"},{"lat":"55.69586425088346","lon":"21.101873824372888"},{"lat":"55.6960675958544","lon":"21.101846415549517"},{"lat":"55.69624001160264","lon":"21.10184323042631"},{"lat":"55.69641628302634","lon":"21.10182219184935"},{"lat":"55.696614012122154","lon":"21.101797549054027"},{"lat":"55.696769915521145","lon":"21.101831747218966"},{"lat":"55.696862032637","lon":"21.101882876828313"},{"lat":"55.69701533764601","lon":"21.10196049325168"},{"lat":"55.69717912003398","lon":"21.102033918723464"},{"lat":"55.69730317220092","lon":"21.102072978392243"},{"lat":"55.697391014546156","lon":"21.102091083303094"},{"lat":"55.69750685244799","lon":"21.102119330316782"},{"lat":"55.69768438115716","lon":"21.10213140025735"},{"lat":"55.69789099507034","lon":"21.102197282016277"},{"lat":"55.69806341081858","lon":"21.102357544004917"},{"lat":"55.698223086073995","lon":"21.10252090729773"},{"lat":"55.69837689399719","lon":"21.102673541754484"},{"lat":"55.69846322759986","lon":"21.102789379656315"},{"lat":"55.69862592034042","lon":"21.102938996627927"},{"lat":"55.69877210073173","lon":"21.10307989642024"},{"lat":"55.698943845927715","lon":"21.103275194764137"},{"lat":"55.69907653145492","lon":"21.103442329913378"},{"lat":"55.69917334243655","lon":"21.10357333905995"},{"lat":"55.69931994192302","lon":"21.10376344062388"},{"lat":"55.6994594167918","lon":"21.103932755067945"},{"lat":"55.69959998130798","lon":"21.104121347889304"},{"lat":"55.69972101598978","lon":"21.104257218539715"},{"lat":"55.69983718916774","lon":"21.104403315111995"},{"lat":"55.699925953522325","lon":"21.104517225176096"},{"lat":"55.70000440813601","lon":"21.10463515855372"},{"lat":"55.700119407847524","lon":"21.104831881821156"},{"lat":"55.700194761157036","lon":"21.104944869875908"},{"lat":"55.700298361480236","lon":"21.105100521817803"},{"lat":"55.70035099983215","lon":"21.105193058028817"},{"lat":"55.700479159131646","lon":"21.105334293097258"},{"lat":"55.70057806558907","lon":"21.10552154481411"},{"lat":"55.70067437365651","lon":"21.105648279190063"},{"lat":"55.70073002949357","lon":"21.105717681348324"},{"lat":"55.7008218113333","lon":"21.10586704686284"},{"lat":"55.70086129009724","lon":"21.10593887977302"},{"lat":"55.70092448964715","lon":"21.106116073206067"},{"lat":"55.700939912348986","lon":"21.106153121218085"},{"lat":"55.70101895369589","lon":"21.106260158121586"},{"lat":"55.70112104527652","lon":"21.10640600323677"},{"lat":"55.701140239834785","lon":"21.106439866125584"},{"lat":"55.70122975856066","lon":"21.10659702681005"},{"lat":"55.70134676992893","lon":"21.106788301840425"},{"lat":"55.70149462670088","lon":"21.107030119746923"},{"lat":"55.7015554793179","lon":"21.107191806659102"},{"lat":"55.70156687870622","lon":"21.10722776502371"},{"lat":"55.70158204995096","lon":"21.10726405866444"},{"lat":"55.70164759643376","lon":"21.107506547123194"},{"lat":"55.7017439045012","lon":"21.10772917047143"},{"lat":"55.701823867857456","lon":"21.107928659766912"},{"lat":"55.701906429603696","lon":"21.108162263408303"},{"lat":"55.701991338282824","lon":"21.108396286144853"},{"lat":"55.702030481770635","lon":"21.10861010849476"},{"lat":"55.702101895585656","lon":"21.108935242518783"},{"lat":"55.70214254781604","lon":"21.10925668850541"},{"lat":"55.702180517837405","lon":"21.109491800889373"},{"lat":"55.70218571461737","lon":"21.109543684870005"},{"lat":"55.70222376845777","lon":"21.109786089509726"},{"lat":"55.702235251665115","lon":"21.109872004017234"},{"lat":"55.702300211414695","lon":"21.11002128571272"},{"lat":"55.70232384838164","lon":"21.110096806660295"},{"lat":"55.702370032668114","lon":"21.110205352306366"},{"lat":"55.702406242489815","lon":"21.11027291044593"},{"lat":"55.70246893912554","lon":"21.110466783866286"},{"lat":"55.70252032019198","lon":"21.11060667783022"},{"lat":"55.70260698907077","lon":"21.11077280715108"},{"lat":"55.70267706178129","lon":"21.110882526263595"},{"lat":"55.70276850834489","lon":"21.111083775758743"},{"lat":"55.702775130048394","lon":"21.111104981973767"},{"lat":"55.70286297239363","lon":"21.11128494143486"},{"lat":"55.70300118997693","lon":"21.111558778211474"},{"lat":"55.70306338369846","lon":"21.111747287213802"},{"lat":"55.70311635732651","lon":"21.111963791772723"},{"lat":"55.70317846722901","lon":"21.1121497862041"},{"lat":"55.70320604369044","lon":"21.112229246646166"},{"lat":"55.70331039838493","lon":"21.112473662942648"},{"lat":"55.70332858711481","lon":"21.112521775066853"},{"lat":"55.703394301235676","lon":"21.112708607688546"},{"lat":"55.70343998260796","lon":"21.112926369532943"},{"lat":"55.70347133092582","lon":"21.113010859116912"},{"lat":"55.703507205471396","lon":"21.113134576007724"},{"lat":"55.70362228900194","lon":"21.113395588472486"},{"lat":"55.70369663648307","lon":"21.11357068642974"},{"lat":"55.70374617353082","lon":"21.11371041275561"},{"lat":"55.703856060281396","lon":"21.11395927146077"},{"lat":"55.70397935807705","lon":"21.114195305854082"},{"lat":"55.704098884016275","lon":"21.11435799859464"},{"lat":"55.70410215295851","lon":"21.11437937244773"},{"lat":"55.70409829728305","lon":"21.114418348297477"},{"lat":"55.703970389440656","lon":"21.114557068794966"},{"lat":"55.70385723374784","lon":"21.114660082384944"},{"lat":"55.703788083046675","lon":"21.11475228331983"},{"lat":"55.70375807583332","lon":"21.11479042097926"},{"lat":"55.70371499285102","lon":"21.114920508116484"},{"lat":"55.70367744192481","lon":"21.115069873631"},{"lat":"55.70365657098591","lon":"21.115141035988927"},{"lat":"55.70362321101129","lon":"21.115276655182242"},{"lat":"55.70356797426939","lon":"21.115418979898095"},{"lat":"55.70342883467674","lon":"21.11560095101595"},{"lat":"55.70326941087842","lon":"21.115726176649332"},{"lat":"55.70318986661732","lon":"21.11577990464866"},{"lat":"55.703066401183605","lon":"21.11588199622929"},{"lat":"55.70296254940331","lon":"21.115961372852325"},{"lat":"55.70288476534188","lon":"21.116036139428616"},{"lat":"55.702633475884795","lon":"21.11627426929772"},{"lat":"55.70257036015391","lon":"21.116339899599552"},{"lat":"55.70243281312287","lon":"21.116461688652635"},{"lat":"55.70231202989817","lon":"21.116568725556135"},{"lat":"55.7021548692137","lon":"21.116699567064643"},{"lat":"55.70210105739534","lon":"21.11675119958818"},{"lat":"55.702026626095176","lon":"21.11681615933776"},{"lat":"55.70182361640036","lon":"21.1170213483274"},{"lat":"55.701650362461805","lon":"21.117181023582816"},{"lat":"55.701496470719576","lon":"21.117324270308018"},{"lat":"55.70132212713361","lon":"21.117485286667943"},{"lat":"55.70119564421475","lon":"21.117601543664932"},{"lat":"55.70102406665683","lon":"21.117759877815843"},{"lat":"55.70085408166051","lon":"21.117912847548723"},{"lat":"55.7006854377687","lon":"21.118055507540703"},{"lat":"55.70051050744951","lon":"21.118215937167406"},{"lat":"55.70034110918641","lon":"21.11837100237608"},{"lat":"55.70016961544752","lon":"21.11850938759744"},{"lat":"55.70001899264753","lon":"21.11847502179444"},{"lat":"55.69988773204386","lon":"21.118254913017154"},{"lat":"55.699858982115984","lon":"21.118093393743038"},{"lat":"55.699802823364735","lon":"21.11786289140582"},{"lat":"55.69972487166524","lon":"21.117673041298985"},{"lat":"55.69963292218745","lon":"21.117400294169784"},{"lat":"55.69957634434104","lon":"21.117237601429224"},{"lat":"55.69949244149029","lon":"21.117088235914707"},{"lat":"55.69936495274305","lon":"21.116900900378823"},{"lat":"55.69922732189298","lon":"21.116730496287346"},{"lat":"55.69912137463689","lon":"21.11659931950271"},{"lat":"55.698979469016194","lon":"21.11641307361424"},{"lat":"55.69888559170067","lon":"21.116287261247635"},{"lat":"55.69878492504358","lon":"21.11615516245365"},{"lat":"55.698687359690666","lon":"21.116036558523774"},{"lat":"55.69857311435044","lon":"21.115854252129793"},{"lat":"55.69844554178417","lon":"21.115700444206595"},{"lat":"55.69828896783292","lon":"21.11554043367505"},{"lat":"55.698210345581174","lon":"21.115515874698758"},{"lat":"55.69815058261156","lon":"21.115539092570543"},{"lat":"55.69802971556783","lon":"21.115668760612607"},{"lat":"55.697909854352474","lon":"21.115807816386223"},{"lat":"55.69778932258487","lon":"21.11594687215984"},{"lat":"55.6977547891438","lon":"21.11598316580057"},{"lat":"55.69764833897352","lon":"21.1160128377378"},{"lat":"55.69745027460158","lon":"21.116042342036963"},{"lat":"55.69733301177621","lon":"21.116149881854653"},{"lat":"55.69723980501294","lon":"21.116232946515083"},{"lat":"55.6972227897495","lon":"21.116261025890708"},{"lat":"55.69715363904834","lon":"21.116349454969168"},{"lat":"55.69708792492747","lon":"21.116425143554807"},{"lat":"55.69701340980828","lon":"21.11648985184729"},{"lat":"55.69685759022832","lon":"21.11659051850438"},{"lat":"55.696704955771565","lon":"21.11672094091773"},{"lat":"55.696525666862726","lon":"21.116858907043934"},{"lat":"55.69639013148844","lon":"21.116948761045933"},{"lat":"55.696241771802306","lon":"21.11704431474209"},{"lat":"55.69608804769814","lon":"21.117151686921716"},{"lat":"55.695942621678114","lon":"21.117259142920375"},{"lat":"55.69578764028847","lon":"21.117350086569786"},{"lat":"55.69563358090818","lon":"21.11743139103055"},{"lat":"55.69551539607346","lon":"21.11752233467996"},{"lat":"55.69535999558866","lon":"21.117640854790807"},{"lat":"55.69524130783975","lon":"21.11772115342319"},{"lat":"55.69511708803475","lon":"21.117845540866256"},{"lat":"55.694992281496525","lon":"21.117994571104646"},{"lat":"55.694970237091184","lon":"21.118015022948384"},{"lat":"55.694850040599704","lon":"21.11820629797876"},{"lat":"55.694762114435434","lon":"21.118307802826166"},{"lat":"55.69462230429053","lon":"21.118422215804458"},{"lat":"55.69453161209822","lon":"21.118590272963047"},{"lat":"55.69442725740373","lon":"21.11873108893633"},{"lat":"55.6943547539413","lon":"21.118875006213784"},{"lat":"55.69434025324881","lon":"21.118914736434817"},{"lat":"55.694283256307244","lon":"21.119155883789062"},{"lat":"55.694209076464176","lon":"21.11935520544648"},{"lat":"55.69414118304849","lon":"21.11953985877335"},{"lat":"55.69409332238138","lon":"21.119693918153644"},{"lat":"55.69401637651026","lon":"21.119905896484852"},{"lat":"55.69391302764416","lon":"21.12019557505846"},{"lat":"55.69383021444082","lon":"21.120406966656446"},{"lat":"55.69374010898173","lon":"21.120611736550927"},{"lat":"55.69366995245218","lon":"21.12077794969082"},{"lat":"55.69358906708658","lon":"21.120989341288805"},{"lat":"55.69350776262581","lon":"21.121180281043053"},{"lat":"55.693437019363046","lon":"21.12135705538094"},{"lat":"55.693372059613466","lon":"21.12154170870781"},{"lat":"55.6933462433517","lon":"21.121611446142197"},{"lat":"55.693264938890934","lon":"21.121894922107458"},{"lat":"55.69322261027992","lon":"21.12200832925737"},{"lat":"55.693137031048536","lon":"21.122179068624973"},{"lat":"55.69298422895372","lon":"21.122334888204932"},{"lat":"55.69281131029129","lon":"21.12247746437788"},{"lat":"55.69267409853637","lon":"21.122561115771532"},{"lat":"55.692514926195145","lon":"21.122676534578204"},{"lat":"55.69232985377312","lon":"21.1228184401989"},{"lat":"55.692206136882305","lon":"21.122904773801565"},{"lat":"55.692184595391154","lon":"21.122915083542466"},{"lat":"55.692057609558105","lon":"21.12300770357251"},{"lat":"55.69194286130369","lon":"21.123074255883694"},{"lat":"55.69183398038149","lon":"21.12316000275314"},{"lat":"55.69173591211438","lon":"21.12329293973744"},{"lat":"55.6916831061244","lon":"21.12344096414745"},{"lat":"55.69161462597549","lon":"21.123603070154786"},{"lat":"55.69151639007032","lon":"21.123859137296677"},{"lat":"55.69143156521022","lon":"21.12404546700418"},{"lat":"55.6913479976356","lon":"21.124228527769446"},{"lat":"55.69128379225731","lon":"21.124351155012846"},{"lat":"55.69121061824262","lon":"21.124528096988797"},{"lat":"55.6911252066493","lon":"21.124728843569756"},{"lat":"55.69101808592677","lon":"21.124975690618157"},{"lat":"55.690926387906075","lon":"21.125151123851538"},{"lat":"55.690736873075366","lon":"21.125306021422148"},{"lat":"55.69059781730175","lon":"21.12537802197039"},{"lat":"55.69040486589074","lon":"21.125512551516294"},{"lat":"55.69023320451379","lon":"21.12565152347088"},{"lat":"55.69006850011647","lon":"21.125793596729636"},{"lat":"55.6899353954941","lon":"21.125906417146325"},{"lat":"55.689752670004964","lon":"21.12604052759707"},{"lat":"55.68956717848778","lon":"21.126177571713924"},{"lat":"55.689404821023345","lon":"21.126235406845808"},{"lat":"55.68924145773053","lon":"21.12626734189689"},{"lat":"55.6890619173646","lon":"21.126314364373684"},{"lat":"55.68879344500601","lon":"21.12650128081441"},{"lat":"55.688646510243416","lon":"21.126614101231098"},{"lat":"55.68847116082907","lon":"21.126740835607052"},{"lat":"55.688291201367974","lon":"21.126871844753623"},{"lat":"55.688115768134594","lon":"21.127001428976655"},{"lat":"55.68796212784946","lon":"21.127109890803695"},{"lat":"55.687809493392706","lon":"21.127204187214375"},{"lat":"55.68767613731325","lon":"21.12729043699801"},{"lat":"55.68748771212995","lon":"21.127318432554603"},{"lat":"55.68730900995433","lon":"21.127259843051434"},{"lat":"55.68715847097337","lon":"21.127320528030396"},{"lat":"55.6869635079056","lon":"21.12742287106812"},{"lat":"55.68678547628224","lon":"21.127511132508516"},{"lat":"55.686605935916305","lon":"21.127605764195323"},{"lat":"55.6864420697093","lon":"21.127705005928874"},{"lat":"55.68629245273769","lon":"21.127832075580955"},{"lat":"55.68617376498878","lon":"21.127942381426692"},{"lat":"55.6860120780766","lon":"21.128108175471425"},{"lat":"55.68582398816943","lon":"21.12822954542935"},{"lat":"55.68569775670767","lon":"21.128230299800634"},{"lat":"55.68557999096811","lon":"21.12821345217526"},{"lat":"55.685403468087316","lon":"21.128289978951216"},{"lat":"55.68525896407664","lon":"21.128417551517487"},{"lat":"55.68512233905494","lon":"21.12855593673885"},{"lat":"55.68504153750837","lon":"21.12874218262732"},{"lat":"55.68503189831972","lon":"21.12878618761897"},{"lat":"55.68502544425428","lon":"21.12883354537189"}]}}';
    points = JSON.parse(points);
    console.log(points); // Here is my full object, i can navigate it and also copy full path
    console.log(points.point[0]); // produces TypeError: points.point is undefined
```

Comment: try console.log(points.points.point[0].lat); What did u get?

Comment: @gjman2 yap, thanks, my fail.

Comment: It works for me if I don't reuse the variable `points` and use different vars for the dom and the string. Seems that JSON.parse does something some kind of in-place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isnt it `points.points.point[0]`? The first 'points' is the variable, not the content.

With another varname it might be a bit more clear:

```
pointsJSON = JSON.parse(pointsJSON);
pointsJSON.points.point[0]
```

Comment: The mega fail from me. Thanks!

Comment: This shows why giving your vars proper names can help your readability and lowers the amount of errors made :) Easy one to misread

Answer (score 1):

As `points` is your object name and with same name your are having property of the object so you can get

```
 points.points.point[0]
```

First points is variable name, second one is first property of object and third one is the inner property